# Pester Tests with PSUseDeclaredVarsMoreThanAssignment

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, pester

If a variable is declared in the `Describe` block of a PSPester script, and it is used in a `It` block, the PSScriptAnalyzer doesn't recognize the usage of that variable.

[image]

How do I have to declare the variable to get rid of the warning, or how do i have to apply the `Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage` for the `PSUseDeclaredVarsMoreThanAssignment` rule to suppress the warning for that single declaration?

Comment: You are not the only one to face this behaviour : https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/711 (or https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/889). Since I use VS Code (1,5 year), this behaviour always happens...

Answer (score 3):

Another work-around would be to assign both variables to the script scope.
It seems like PSScriptAnalyzer is trying to be clever and sees the curly braces as sub-scopes. Therfore the `$foo` variable is not used in the `BeforeEach` scope, but is used although not assigned in the `It`scope.

EX: `$script:foo` [does not result in a linting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohwXS.png).

The actual solution would be to help the vscode-powershell extension development. That might be more difficult though.